# Should msg.value always be even number?

Tags: solidity, blockchain

On  [official solidity page](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/solidity-by-example.html) , there is an example Safe remote purchase, in that example there is a payable function Purchase, and function firsts checks if msg.value is even or odd. I want to know if that is just for purpose of demonstration or is there any significance of that code.

Comment: `msg.value` can be even/odd. I guess that's only for demonstration. If you need even value in msg.value (like in case where you want to distribute 2 equal parts t2 addresses), you can have a check like that else if you don't need that check, skip this.

Comment: Note that in practice if you need to split ETH into two parts, checking that `msg.value` is even is somewhat unnecessary. The difference is 1 Wei, which is an incredibly small amount

Comment: @TjadenHess Yeah obviously that's negligible, but if we have to do it million times, it will matter, so I guess if we can handle the case, we should. :)

Comment: Honestly, even if you do it a million times, were talking about 10^-12 ETH, or around 1 trillionth of a cent

Answer (score 1):

> Should msg.value always be even number?

Not necessarily. `msg.value` is amount send in Wei (1 ether = 10^18 Wei). So there is no such rule for msg.value to be even.

It all depends on your requirement. If you want your `msg.value`  be an even number. You can check for that else just go ahead with whatever value you receive in msg.value.

There are a number of ways to check for even values. One being:

```
function checkEven(uint testNo) constant returns(bool){
        uint remainder = testNo%2;
        if(remainder==0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Note: You are referring develop documentation of solidity. For latest version see : [latest solidity documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contributing.html)

Answer (score 0):

*msg.value* gives you  total number of wei sent with the message.So not necessarily it should be even.  In that  [example](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/solidity-by-example.html) function first checks if msg.value is even or odd based on requirement.